# From subprocess.Popen to multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I got a function that invokes a process using `subprocess.Popen` in the following way:

```
    def func():
        ...
        process = subprocess.Popen(substr, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        timeout = {"value": False}
        timer = Timer(timeout_sec, kill_proc, [process, timeout])
        timer.start()

        for line in process.stdout:
            lines.append(line)

        timer.cancel()
        if timeout["value"] == True:
            return 0
        ...
```

I call this function from other function using a loop (e.g from range(1,100) ) , how can I make multiple calls to the function with multiprocessing? that each time several processes will run in parallel

The processes doesn't depend on each other, the only constraint is that each process would be 'working' on only one index (e.g no two processes will work on index 1)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you pass any arguments in `substr`?

Comment: Yes, `substr` is different in each call

Comment: Is the type of process.stdout then compatible with multiprocess.Pipe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add the index to your `Popen` call and create a [worker pool](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) with as many CPU cores you have available.

```
import multiprocessing

def func(index):
    ....
    process = subprocess.Popen(substr + " --index {}".format(index), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    p.map(func, range(1, 100))
```

Comment: No need to pass the `cpu_count` parameter to the `Pool`. Python will do it for you by default.

Comment: @noxdafox Thanks for paying attention! This was actually on purpose to make it more clear, otherwise it all looks like magic.